# Copy/Paste last two rows into next empty row and clear certain cells (contains merged cells)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a command button up the top of my sheet which when pressed will copy the last 2 rows in columns A:AJ that have data and paste into the next empty row below them. I want the source style and formulas to be copied but not the manually entered data. I have an image here too to help:

[image]

So for example from the image. I want to copy rows 105/106 together and then paste them to 107/108 as they are the next empty rows(although hidden so would also need to unhide those rows). 
Everything in those 2 rows should be copied except the bottom "strokes" section and par/strokes box is a formula/date/data validation/dropdown which I want copied but the strokes section to be empty as well as date/dropdown be blank too.  I would like it to all look the same as well (copy the style). Filled cells to clear in that scenario would be column B, C, E:M, P:X but only on the "STROKES" row.

To put it even more basically. I want a button to push that will add another row to the table. So I have 52 there in the picture you can see, when pressed I will now have 53 below it and it be blank ready for use.

If the hidden rows need to be unhidden for this to work I can do that.

I have looked to try do it myself but I've never done anything with VBA before so I have no idea.
I hope someone can understand this request and that it is even doable. 
Thanks.

Based on DecimalTurn's answer, I made some changes and here's my new code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Find the last row based on column D (4th)
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

'Copy the range
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (LastRow - 1) & ":" & "AJ" & LastRow).Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (LastRow + 1) & ":" & "AJ" & LastRow + 2).PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False 'This will clear the clipboard

'Adjust numbering
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Value2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LastRow - 1).Value2 + 1

'Clear content
Dim ListOfColumnsToClear1() As Variant
Dim ListOfColumnsToClear2() As Variant
ListOfColumnsToClear1 = Array("B:C")
ListOfColumnsToClear2 = Array("E:M", "P:X")

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(ListOfColumnsToClear1) To UBound(ListOfColumnsToClear1)

    Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (LastRow + 1) & ":" & "AJ" & LastRow + 2), ActiveSheet.Range(ListOfColumnsToClear1(i))).ClearContents

Next i
For i = LBound(ListOfColumnsToClear2) To UBound(ListOfColumnsToClear2)


    Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (LastRow + 2) & ":" & "AJ" & LastRow + 2), ActiveSheet.Range(ListOfColumnsToClear2(i))).ClearContents

    Next i

End Sub
```

It's probably completely wrong but it did work.

Comment: Filled cells to delete in that scenario would be column B105, C105, E106:M106, P106:X106

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you are trying to do with VBA, I would suggest to have your code do the following (in that order):

1. Find the last row of data.
2. Define the range to copy and copy that range.
3. Ajust line numbering
4. Clear the content of the cells that need manual inputs.

Assuming you don't need to unhide any rows, the code would look like this:

```
Sub CopyLastTwoRows()

    'Find the last row based on column D (4th)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    'Copy the range
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (LastRow - 1) & ":" & "AJ" & LastRow).Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (LastRow + 1) & ":" & "AJ" & LastRow + 2).PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'This will clear the clipboard

    'Adjust numbering
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Value2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LastRow - 1).Value2 + 1

    'Clear content
    Dim ListOfColumnsToClear() As Variant
    ListOfColumnsToClear = Array("B:C", "E:M", "P:X")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(ListOfColumnsToClear) To UBound(ListOfColumnsToClear)

        Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (LastRow + 2) & ":" & "AJ" & LastRow + 2), ActiveSheet.Range(ListOfColumnsToClear(i))).ClearContents

    Next i

End Sub
```

Now, since you have merged cells, the section where we clear data will give you an error since only the bottom part of your **merged cells** will intersect. To solve this, we can use a function that will make sure that if there are merged cells in our range, all their cells will be included.

The code would look like this (note the new function at the end):

```
Sub CopyLastTwoRows()

    'Find the last row based on column D (4th)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    'Copy the range
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (LastRow - 1) & ":" & "AJ" & LastRow).Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (LastRow + 1) & ":" & "AJ" & LastRow + 2).PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'This will clear the clipboard

    'Adjust numbering
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Value2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LastRow - 1).Value2 + 1

    'Clear content
    Dim ListOfColumnsToClear() As Variant
    ListOfColumnsToClear = Array("B:C", "E:M", "P:X")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(ListOfColumnsToClear) To UBound(ListOfColumnsToClear)

        ExpandToIncludeMergedCells(Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (LastRow + 2) & ":" & "AJ" & LastRow + 2), ActiveSheet.Range(ListOfColumnsToClear(i)))).ClearContents

    Next i

End Sub

Private Function ExpandToIncludeMergedCells(ByRef Rng As Range) As Range

    Dim TempRange As Range
    Set TempRange = Rng.Cells(1)

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Rng

        Set TempRange = Union(TempRange, c.MergeArea)

    Next c

    Set ExpandToIncludeMergedCells = TempRange

End Function
```

Finally, if you want to do this multiple times (say 10 times) by pressing a button, you would simply do:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        CopyLastTwoRows
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Note that I'm using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to tell Excel not to refresh the screen while the macro is running. This will make your code run much faster, but it's recommended to set it back to true at the end and to have some [error handling](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/) (which I didn't include here).

Comment: Hi that works great except the formulas in the yellow "Par" row you see in the picture don't get copied. Everything else does apart from that.

Comment: @Simon  You mean that nothing on row 105 gets copied?

Comment: Everything gets copied except for the fomulas on 105 between E:M and P:X. All formulas in other cells get copied. I assume it has to do with them not being merged unlike all the other cells. I'm not sure. I did change the first line to Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() as I want it at a button press.

Comment: Actually it will be because of the clear section. It's clearing both rows in that range rather than just the bottom one.

Comment: @Simon  I just made the change. Let me know if that works.

Comment: It did it but also gave merged cell error. I changed it and will edit your post and put what I did in. Seems to work. If you could also do a 3rd code under it for me where it would work doing say 10 "rows"(so 20 actual rows) instead of 1 at a time?

Comment: @Simon If you don't mind, I think it's better if you change you answer instead of my answer. I'm going to suggest something to deal with the merged cells problem and add an option for more than one row.

Comment: Sorry I did edit it but needed to be reviewed but it's gone now. I edited my original question

Comment: @Simon  No worries, I've edited my answer by adding a new section. Let me know if that solves your issue.

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy golfing :)

Comment: Hey just one more annoying thing. If I wanted another button that could clear all of the used rows all together (to the same parameters as above) how would one change that clear content section you have?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, but feel free to create a new question if you need further help.

Comment: Did a new question. Thanks.