# Clearing Contents of merged cells,specific columns, every other row and unknown last row using command button

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to create a "Clear Page" command button for this log I'm working on.

[image]

That's an example image I used in a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634637/copy-paste-last-two-rows-into-next-empty-row-and-clear-certain-cells-contains-m/57635050) which may be useful to anyone able to help. This was adding more table rows to the end of the sheet. It also had a clear content function but was only for the new rows being inserted.

I need this button to be able to clear columns B:C , E:M , & P:X of the entire sheet from Row 3,4 down to the last used row. As you can see there are merged cells so the rows are always paired in twos. Rows 3&4 are the first table row and 105&106 are currently the last(52) but that can change(as more may get added) which is why I can't have a specific last row and the formula needs to find it.

The only thing is I cannot have it clear the "PAR" section of E:M & P:X as it has formulas in it. I only want the "STROKES" section underneath to be cleared. This will be the same for every table row.

Columns B & C are obviously merged so I don't know whether it needs to be the top row cleared or bottom or both in terms of the formula.
Hopefully that's all understandable. Thanks.

Comment: Merged cells are evil. If you can reformat your log to not merge cells that would make your life easier. You can also 'centre across cells' in the formatting without actually merging (not sure if it only works horizontally). Your other option is to unmerge cells in your code and then do you clearing.

Comment: You can check link I posted where he provided me an option to clear contents of new cells added(I edited question with more info above). I do need the merged cells because I need two rows for the "PARS" and "STROKES" sections then the rest are merged. I can work with it unmerging -> clearing -> re-mergining if that's possible. I don't really mind how it's done as long as once cleared it ends up the same but those sections mentioned blank.

Comment: Do you have any data beneath what you deem as the last row?

Comment: No, as in picture currently row 106 is last. There is nothing below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```
Public Sub ClearSheet()
    Dim lngFirstRow As Long, objSheet As Worksheet

    lngFirstRow = 3

    On Error Resume Next

    ' Change "Sheet1" to the name of your worksheet
    ' Set objSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set objSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    With objSheet
        .Range("B" & lngFirstRow & ":C" & .Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Cells.ClearContents
        .Range("E" & lngFirstRow & ":M" & .Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Cells.ClearContents
        .Range("P" & lngFirstRow & ":X" & .Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Cells.ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

... it selects the non formula cells within the columns and then clears the contents.

Comment: Hi that works great. Is it possible to have it auto select the current sheet instead of me inputting it because I would also duplicate the sheet in future? I just tried doing that and the code stays the same.

Comment: @Simon, done!  Please mark as the answer if you're happy.  I'm sick of having to ask people to do that.  :-)

Comment: Thanks and of course. I don't do until I've fully sorted or it's as far as can go. Cheers.